# Help hiding css popup in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, popup

I am trying to create a custom Facebook Tab using iframes.  Anyways, it has a popup when it first loads.  However, this popup doesn't display correctly when shown in Internet Explorer.

I tried the below code so I could attempt to hind the popup altogether, but it didn't work.

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    --> 

#hidepopup {
   display: none;
   }

    <!--
<![endif]-->
```

With the popup code between `<div id="hidepopup">` & `</div>`

Any suggestions on how to hide or resize it?

http://www.facebook.com/pages/GTD/104839016256119?sk=app_168848466497060

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if IE]>

<style type="text/css">
#hidepopup {
   display: none;
   }
</style>

<![endif]-->
```

Do not use `!` because it means `not` IE and you have extra opening/closing tags for comments. Also you have not declared that it is style. Here is link to help you with conditional comments: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Your second issue is that you are using jQuery for animating popup. Animations are changing `display:none` to `display: block`. So your special condition for IE is overwritten by script.
here:

```
//transition effect
$(id).fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here.

- The conditional used is a IE conditional directive specifying: if not IE, these are IE only so it is a bit backwards
- The conditional is incomplete the end comment happens immediately after the first condition.

Try This:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
   #hidepopup {
     display: none;
   }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```